# Merge/paste csv files based on a column value

Tags: php, bash, csv, unix, centos

I don't find any specific example on php or linux to do this:

**1st csv file**:

```
field1;field2;field3;...
   one;   two; three;...
```

**2nd csv file**:

```
field4;field3;field7;...
 some;  three;     ok;
 some;   four;  notok;
```

as you can see, they have **field3** in common

so, where **field3.1st csv = field3.2nd csv** eg. three=three here,

I need the final csv:

```
field1;field2;field3;field4;field3;field7 
   one;   two; three;  some; three;   ok;
   ...
   ...
   ...
```

I tried to do it with php

```
$lines = file($csvone);
$lined = file($csvtwo);
$listf = "/home/myuser/public_html/folder/finallist.csv";
$fh = fopen($listf, 'wa+') or die("can't open file");
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
  $arr = explode(";",$line);
  $ref = $arr[2];
  $ref = rtrim($ref);
  echo "$ref \n";
  foreach ($lined as $fine_num => $fine) { 
        $brr = explode(";",$fine);
        $refe = $brr[1];
        $refe = rtrim($refe);
        echo "$refe \n";
        if ($ref == $refe) {
            echo "$ref equal to $refe ! \n";
         $stringData = "$arr[0];$arr[1];$arr[2];$arr[3];$arr[4];$arr[5];$arr[6];$arr[7];$arr[8];$arr[9];$arr[10];$arr[11];$brr[0];$brr[1];$brr[2];$brr[3];$brr[4];$brr[5];$brr[6];$brr[7];$brr[8];$brr[9];$brr[10];$brr[11];$brr[12];$brr[13]";  
        $stringData = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),"",$stringData);
        $stringData .= PHP_EOL;
        fwrite($fh, $stringData); 
        }

    } 
}  
 fclose($fh);
```

obviously it works but it takes too long time (really too much).

Please, what's the fastest method to do it?

Also appreciated a solution by linux command line (CentOS, if possible)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `break;` if your matches found and written in your final CSV like,

```
if ($ref == $refe) {
    echo "$ref equal to $refe ! \n";
    $stringData = "$arr[0];$arr[1];$arr[2];$arr[3];$arr[4];$arr[5];$arr[6];$arr[7];$arr[8];$arr[9];$arr[10];$arr[11];$brr[0];$brr[1];$brr[2];$brr[3];$brr[4];$brr[5];$brr[6];$brr[7];$brr[8];$brr[9];$brr[10];$brr[11];$brr[12];$brr[13]";  
    $stringData = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),"",$stringData);
    $stringData .= PHP_EOL;
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    break; // break the loop here for unwanted cycles
}
```

Also, if you used a row from `$lined` array then you can unset it, so that your `$lined` array would be short and your second loop will iterate less.
Just use the below line before using `break;`

```
unset($lined[$fine_num]);
```

Your second loop can be optimised like,

```
foreach ($lined as $fine_num => $fine) { 
    $brr = explode(";",$fine);
    $refe = $brr[1];
    $refe = rtrim($refe);
    echo "$refe \n";
    if ($ref == $refe) {
        echo "$ref equal to $refe ! \n";
        $stringData = "$arr[0];$arr[1];$arr[2];$arr[3];$arr[4];$arr[5];$arr[6];$arr[7];$arr[8];$arr[9];$arr[10];$arr[11];$brr[0];$brr[1];$brr[2];$brr[3];$brr[4];$brr[5];$brr[6];$brr[7];$brr[8];$brr[9];$brr[10];$brr[11];$brr[12];$brr[13]";  
        $stringData = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),"",$stringData);
        $stringData .= PHP_EOL;
        fwrite($fh, $stringData); 
        unset($lined[$fine_num]); // unset so that next time loop will interate less
        break; // break here
    }
}
```

Comment: you're right, forgot about unset and break...and it works faster, but unfortunately not so fast as i need, because there are more than 100.000 lines on the csv...I think that there's something better, maybe with awk or php itself...

Comment: then, are you sure that unset here is at the correct place? I'm not sure about the logic. The value is loaded anyway into the array the second time...? because the main foreach is the other. How you would do it?

Comment: Yes it is at correct place, it should be removed when the row is added in your final CSV and then break it. Because the second loop is running 100000 times for each iteration of outer loop, so reducing the second one is a good option.

Comment: @RohanKumar, depending on the size of each text file, storing the first CSV file in a map/dictionary keyed by the col 3 value would be a /lot/ faster, e.g. linear time. One loop adds the first CSV to the map, the second reads in the second CSV and checks for the values in the map, rather than looping through the first CSV every time.

Comment: well, the echoing test was slowing down for sure...anyway now 30 mins and it did half of the file... do you think that 1 hour is acceptable? lol

Comment: if most of the refs are even on the 2nd file it takes half of the time...I can accept the answer because of this, but for sure the issue is when not any ref is on the 2nd file...because it's slowing down a bit